# Gzip Format Decompress - Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am compressing the Json into Gzip format and sending as below:

```
connection.setDoOutput(true); // sets POST method implicitly
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Encoding", "gzip"); 

final byte[] originalBytes = body.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(originalBytes.length);
final ByteArrayEntity postBody = new ByteArrayEntity(baos.toByteArray());                       
method.setEntity(postBody);
```

I want to receive the Post request and decompress that to a string.What `@Consumes` annotation i should use for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle gzip-encoding transparent for your resource-classes like [described in the docmentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e8344) with a `ReaderInterceptor`. 
The interceptor could look like this:

```
@Provider
public class GzipReaderInterceptor implements ReaderInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Object aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorContext context)  throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        if ("gzip".equals(context.getHeaders().get("Content-Encoding"))) {
            InputStream originalInputStream = context.getInputStream();
            context.setInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(originalInputStream));
        }
        return context.proceed();
    }

}
```

For your resource class the gzipping is transparent. It can still consume `application/json`. 
You also don't need to handle a byte array, just use a POJO like you would normally do:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response post(Person person) { /* */ }
```

One problem might also be your client code. 
I'm not sure if you are really gzipping the post body so here is a full example that posts a gzipped entity with a `URLConnection`:

```
String entity = "{\"firstname\":\"John\",\"lastname\":\"Doe\"}";

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
gzos.write(entity.getBytes("UTF-8"));
gzos.close();

URLConnection connection = new URL("http://whatever").openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
connection.connect();
baos.writeTo(connection.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: thanks...but how to handle the return value from the interceptors in the method.

Comment: will it be like this.....public String Gzip(byte[] json) {
        String str = ... // very long string
        return str;
    }

Comment: The creation of GZipInputStream will fail if the originalInputStream is empty (ie request with empty body).